# Protractor Select Object Which is On Top

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

I have a test I am trying to create where I change the name of a card. The problem is there is a hidden error card which has the exact same identifiers as what I am trying to edit. The test returns that the object I am trying to work with is unreachable, which makes sense, it is under the one I am working with.

The locator which I have is: `textarea[ng-model="ctrl.currentChartTitle"]`.

Yes, I know that I can do this by model and tried that, but it yields the same results.

Here is a screenshot of the html the yellow is the on top object I am trying to reach:

[image: HTML]

Not really sure how do to do the selector for this, so it always works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a bit more searching and found a solution. It looks a like this:

```
    chartTitleTextArea = this.visualizer.all(by.css('textarea[ng-model="ctrl.currentChartTitle"]')).filter((element) => {
    return element.isDisplayed().then((isDisplayed) => {
        return isDisplayed
      })
    }).first()
```

Basically, what this is doing is getting all of the elements which match that locator. Then filtering them on if `isDisplayed()` is true. Then grabbing the first one.